# If $n\mid m$ and $m\mid r$, then $n\mid(r+r^2)$

Tags: proof-verification, divisibility

I am struggling with a direct proof involving divisibility. I have been struggling with proofs all semester.

What I'm trying to prove: $n, m, r \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $n\mid m$ and $m\mid r$, then $n\mid(r+r^2)$

So far for this proof I only have a very basic setup, but not sure where to go from here

I have $$ n\mid m, i \in \mathbb{Z}, m=ni$$

$$ m\mid r, j \in \mathbb{Z}, r=mj$$

and trying to prove that $$\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}, (r+r^2)=nk$$

I then have $$r+r^2 = (mj+(mj)^2)$$
$$=(mj+(mj)(mj))$$
$$=mj(1+mj)$$

Since $r=mj$ I substituted $mj$ in for $r$. I'm not completely sure I'm heading in the right direction, maybe I should substitute $m$ as $ni$ so that it would look more like this:

$$r+r^2=(nij+(nij)^2)$$
$$=(nij+(nij)(nij))$$
$$=nij(1+(nij))$$

As I said, I am really struggling with proofs this semester, so any help would be greatly appreciated to help make sense of this. It's hard to prove anything when you second guess every step you take.

Comment: Compensatory upvote.  I wish most OPs included this much of an attempt.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, do you consider changing `|` into `\mid` such an important issue, worth editing posts to perform this change, hunting for every occurence of `|`?

Comment: Thanks, Brian. I wouldn't feel right asking for help if I didn't at least show what I have and where I am struggling.

Comment: Michael, the transitivity "$a\mid b,b\mid c$ implies $a\mid c$" makes it much easier. I can understand that you want to finish your proof first, but this way the proof becomes really short and clear. Also, it always works, e.g., we also have, ays, $n\mid r+r^2+r^3$, without using more $nij$ and $nj$.

Comment: @AlexM. : $\ldots\,$and other copy-editing$\,\ldots$ Editing a posting doesn't take much. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there! You got as far as

$$r+r^2=nij(1+nij)$$

But this means that $n$ divides $r+r^2$, because $n$ divides $n \times ij(1+nij)$. That's all you need!

Comment: Thank you. So my second attempt was more accurate than my first. Now I just need to mention that $nij(1+nij)$ is an integer which will divide $r+r^2$?

Comment: No no no no no....$nij(1+nij)$ is _equal_ to $r+r^2$. As you yourself showed.

Answer (score 2):

If we have $n\mid m$ and $m\mid r$ we also have $n\mid r$, this has been shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538423/for-all-integers-a-b-c-if-a-b-and-b-c-then-a-c) on MSE, and is easy to see: write $m=an$ and $r=bm$, then $r=abn$. But then again, apply transitivity. Because $n\mid r$ and $r\mid r^2$ it follows that $n\mid r^2$, and then of course also $n\mid r+r^2$.